# How to use Join in Codeigniter for update Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have given my Codeigniter code below, here i need to update a record using join conditions. I used the below code, But shows error

```
$condition="a.assignto='0' and a.recstatus='1' and b.location='$location' and '$category' IN(SELECT categoryid FROM `tq_productcategory` where productid=c.productid and recstatus='1')";
$this->db->set($data);
$this->db->where($condition);
$this->db->limit($limit);
$this->db->join('tq_customer b','a.customerid=b.customerid');
$this->db->join('tq_product c','a.productid=c.productid');
$this->db->order_by("a.created_on", "asc");
$this->db->update('tq_customerservicesupport a');
```

Below is my error Msg

```
 Unknown column 'b.location' in 'where clause'

UPDATE `tq_customerservicesupport` `a` SET `assignto` = '10' WHERE `a`.`assignto` = '0' and `a`.`recstatus` = '1' and `b`.`location` = '3227' and '1' IN(SELECT categoryid FROM `tq_productcategory` where productid = `c`.`productid` and `recstatus` = '1') ORDER BY `a`.`created_on` ASC LIMIT 1

Filename: D:/wamp/www/tooquik/system/database/DB_driver.php
```

Comment: Put your $this->db->update('tq_customerservicesupport a'); below join query

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan Tried,but same issue

Comment: ON your tq_customer table location exists?

Comment: yes it is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tq_customerservicesupport AS a JOIN tq_customer AS b ON a.customerid = b.customerid JOIN tq_product AS c ON  a.productid = c.productid SET $data WHERE $condition ORDER BY a.created_on ASC LIMIT $limit";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Make sure that the query is correct cause i just wrote it based on your data and better to check it in phpmyadmin to make sure it works fine with no errors.